# Filtering even numbers in python

Tags: python, numpy

just started with python and wanted to filter the even numbers from a numpy array:

```
>array = np.arange(2,10000)
>>print(array)
```

I know that the remainder of even no./2 should be 0, so part of the filtering condition should look somehow like this:

```
>if x%2 == 0
```

But no matter how, I always get an error of some kind. btw I'm using Python 3.

Thanks and Best

Answer (score 11):

One Liner as pointed by Mikel:

```
print(np.arange(2,10000,2))
```

This creates an array starting from 2 ending at 10k with a step size of 2 i.e every second number.

Or if you want to use modulus you can try like this:

```
ar = np.arange(2,10000)
ar = ar[ar%2==0]
print(ar)
```

Output:

```
array([   2,    4,    6, ..., 9994, 9996, 9998])
```

`ar%2==0` creates a boolean mask to include only even numbers

Comment: it actually worked, thanks!

Comment: @palacinak Consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your problem.

Comment: a one liner: np.arange(2,10000,2)